# Laravel route with attribute to a function

Tags: redirect, routes, laravel

This is probable a very simple one.

I have a function for the index that either lists everything or a specific item based on an optional parameter passed to it.

I have this route for the controller:

```
Route::controller('movies/(:any)');
```

I want to redirect it to the movies index function with the parameter in place.
I dont want people to have to type:
www.site.com/movies/index/2
but instead
www.site.com/movies/2

I have tried a Question mark in the any array and a 'closure' function (I think thats the right terminology) to allow me to redirect.

The closure attempt looked like this:

```
Route::controller('movies/(:any?)',function($id){
    return Redirect::to("movie/index/$id");
});
```

This gives me a 404 error.
Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont want to distiquish that on your Route, let the controller decide what to do.

Your Route:

```
Route::get('movies/(:any)', 'movies@index');
```

Your Controller:

```
class Movies_Controller extends Base_Controller {

    public $restful = true; // i have this line on my Base_Controller

    function get_index($id = null)
    {
        if( ! is_null($id))
        {
            // return the movie
        }

        // return all movies
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats the one. Didn't realise you could route like that. Nor that you had to declare RESTful as true. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your route should be like this

```
Route::any("movies/{id}","MovieController@index");
```

Also, the function should be like

```
public function index( $id = "" ){
   //Your code here
}
```